# Data is not passed to view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, storyboard

I want to pass an "human" that was selected in a `tableView` to a `detailViewController`. I connected them in Interface Builder via Storyboards and set up an own segue identifier. The `NSLog` is called but it returns `(null)`. Also, the in the detailView, nothing is shown but the default content…

My `tableViewController`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{ 
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"didSelectRow"]) {
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    Human *employee = [[Human alloc] init];
    employee = [people objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]]; 
    [detailViewController setHuman:employee];

}
}
```

And the `detailViewController`

```
-(void)setHuman:(Human *)human
{
NSLog(@"%@",employee.name);
employee = human;
nameLab.text = employee.name;
descriptionLab.text = employee.description;
imageViewBig.image = [employee imageForName];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `human` in `setHuman` contains `employee`. Thus you should assign the variable `human` to the `@property` `human` of the `DetailViewController` in your function. Or better still, just assign the property from outside: `detailViewController.human = employee`.

Your `NSLog` returns null because you call it **before** assigning `human` to `employee`.

Maybe choosing less repetitive ivar names would help.